# Wordpress custom $wpdb query order by custom field

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am using advanced custom fields wordpress plugin and a custom post type called "albums".
In the custom post type I have 2 custom fields.
One is a "user"-type-field called "album_artists" which stores an array with user ids into the database.
The other one is a field called "release_date" which stores a timestamp into the database and is a required field.
Now, in authors.php I get all "album"-posts that contain the current author's id in the "album_artists" field. So far so good. I managed this with a custom query which looks for \"{userID}\" in the serialized array of the "album_artists"-field and I am able to get the posts that I want. But now I want to order the albums-posts (which are currently ordered by post date) by the other custom field's ("release_date") value with the timestamp in it.

Is it possible with a single SQL query or is there any other idea to achieve this? Here's my custom query:

```
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results("
        SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE `ID` IN (
            SELECT `post_id`
            FROM $wpdb->postmeta
            WHERE `meta_key` LIKE 'album_artists'
            AND `meta_value` LIKE '%\"{$curauth->ID}\"%'
        )
        AND `post_type` LIKE 'albums'
        AND `post_status` LIKE 'publish'
        ORDER BY 'post_date' ASC
", OBJECT);
```

Comment: i believe you need to extract data, serialize and then sort .

Comment: yeah but this can't be done with SQL alone right? So I'd have to pull out ALL albums which will cause a huge query. But I actually don't think I need to unserialize first because in the database the array looks like this: a:2:{i:0;s:1:"6";i:1;s:1:"3";} (width the ID in quotes) That's the reason why I look for \"{$curauth->ID}\" (width quotes). I think this is safe, isn't it?

Comment: you should make sure that irrelevant data must not be formatted as the same pattern when using **pattern matching** approach

Comment: Yeah I understand but I think I can use it safely. Thank for the advice. I know it's not the most beautiful way, but well it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use WP_Query with meta key/values to do this. Here is my code, just test it.

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'album',
'orderby' => 'meta_value',
'meta_query' => array(array('key' => 'release_date')),
'order' => 'ASC',
'paged'=>$paged,
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key'     => 'album_artists',
        'value'   => $curauth->ID,
        'compare' => 'LIKE',
    ),
),
);
```

You can use `'order' => 'ASC',` to `'order' => 'DESC',` change the order of sorting

Comment: Hey, thanks for the advice! I'm gonna give it a try although I'd have to use 'value'   => '\"' . $curauth->ID . '\"' to look for the quotes (see my answer to arkoak). I'll check if this will work, otherwise I am gonna go for M Khalid's solution

Comment: that't fine. Just check it. I have tested it though.

Comment: Yeah it works great when I don't escape the quotes  'value'   => '"' . $curauth->ID . '"'. Thank's for your efforts! Answer accepted

Comment: It's great pleasure that you could solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use joins for order by i have joined `postmeta` again to get the `meta_value` i.e date for `meta_key` release_date since `meta_value` type is text you need to cast your string date value so that it becomes MySQL's date object and can be used in ordering results, in `STR_TO_DATE` provide your current string date format like if date is stored as `04/26/2015` then format will be `'%m/%d/%Y'`

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.*
FROM $wpdb->posts p
JOIN $wpdb->postmeta m ON p.`ID` = m.post_id
JOIN $wpdb->postmeta m1 ON p.`ID` = m1.post_id
WHERE m.`meta_key` LIKE 'album_artists'
AND m.`meta_value` LIKE '%\"{$curauth->ID}\"%'
AND m1.`meta_key` LIKE 'release_date'
AND p.`post_type` LIKE 'albums'
AND p.`post_status` LIKE 'publish'
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(m1.meta_value, '%m/%d/%Y') ASC
```

Comment: I'll check that out, thank you for your efforts! So if I understand it correctly for example in "JOIN $wpdb->postmeta m1 ON p.`ID` = m1.post_id" the "m1" is a shortcut to add a second instance of the postmeta-table (to use for order by)? I see I should really spend a day or two to get deeper into the whole sql thing, there's more to it than I thought

Comment: @JonathanHoller yup you are right second join for order by to get value for `release_date`

Comment: This works great but I'll go for @Ajith 's approach because it's notably faster and probably safer to use it this more "wordpressy" way. Thank you anyway for your help