# Wordpress Query by Meta key, type date numeric

Tags: php, wordpress

Ii have problem with WP Query, can't order by meta key
I use [Event Manager](http://wp-events-plugin.com/) plugin, and need query 4 post on my [Homepage](http://portanova.hr/),
I need post only current and future events(posts) and sort by start date.
Here is my code

```
$time = date('Y-m-d');
$timeStro = strtotime($time);
$myNewQuery = new WP_query(
        array(
                    'post_type' => 'event',
                    'featured' => 'yes',
                    'meta_key' => 'event_start_date',
                    'meta_type' => 'numeric',
                    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
                    'order' => 'ASC',
                    'showposts' => 4,
                    'meta_query' => array(
                            array(
                                    'key' => strtotime('_event_end_date'),
                                    'value' => $timeStro,
                                    'type' => 'numeric',
                                    'compare' => '>='
                                )
                        )

            ));
```

Thanks you all! :)

At the end, we must hardcode and make our query from DB

```
       <?php
           global $wpdb;
           $time = date('Y-m-d');
           $events = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_em_events WHERE     event_end_date >= '$time' ORDER BY event_start_date LIMIT 4");

  foreach($events as $event) {
?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($event->post_id); ?>">
                    <div class="div-calendar-entry">
                        <p class="calendar-title"><?php echo $event->event_name; ?></p> 
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please use

```
'key' => ('metakey_slug')
```

in place-of

```
'key' => strtotime('_event_end_date')
```

Comment: Meta compare works, but i can't sort by(orderby) _event_start_date, tnx :)

Comment: at the end i must hardcode :(

  <?php


           global $wpdb;
           $time = date('Y-m-d');
         $events = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_em_events WHERE  event_end_date >= '$time' ORDER BY event_start_date LIMIT 4");

foreach($events as $event) { .................

Comment: try to get any help from this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29895792/wordpress-custom-wpdb-query-order-by-custom-field/29897079#29897079

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with the following:

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$today = date( 'Y-m-d' );
$upcoming_events = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT post_id FROM wp_em_events WHERE event_start_date >= '$today' ORDER BY event_start_date LIMIT 100" );
if ( $upcoming_events ) {
    $upcoming_events_post_ids = wp_list_pluck( $upcoming_events, 'post_id' );
    $upcoming_events_args     = [
        'post_type'      => 'event',
        'post__in'       => $upcoming_events_post_ids,
        'orderby'        => 'post__in',
        'posts_per_page' => 100,
    ];
    $upcoming_events_query    = new WP_Query( $upcoming_events_args );
    if ( $upcoming_events_query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $upcoming_events_query->have_posts() ) :
            $upcoming_events_query->the_post();
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/event' );
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
}
?>
```